# cherokee doesn't synchronic update django process code

Tags: django, webserver, cherokee

I use cherokee(1.0) as web server and django web framework(1.2.1).

When I update django files like views.py or static files, web server seems
not to update instantly. I guess it is about cache, so i set expiration "already expired on 1970", but the problem remains.

I also try to restart server in admin website, but still can't solve the problem.

how can it update synchronicly or can I update it by myself?

Comment: Do you use uWSGI to server the django application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to kill all fcgi processes.
ps -ef | grep fcgi|awk '{print $2}'|xargs sudo kill -9

===================================

I asked cherokee project and get response below:

Comment 1 by hcarvalhoalves, Yesterday (30 hours ago)
This happens because the request is still being served by an old FastCGI process. After code changes, you don't have to restart Cherokee, but instead restart the FastCGI process. For that, you can start django passing the PID file parameter (configure this under Sources):

./manage runfcgi ... pidfile=/var/run/django-fcgi.pid

Then later, when you change code, restart the fcgi process with:

kill -HUP `cat /var/run/django-fcgi.pid

Not a bug on Cherokee at all, as it doesn't touch any python files, just serves thru FCGI.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is supposed to happen.

You will need to restart the server after code changes.

Comment: I try to restart cherokee in admin web but the problem remains.